# Check original language of repository objects at creation?

Tags: abap

In our company, repository objects must be created with original language EN. 
Is there a way to check the logon language in case of creating a new object in the ABAP repository?

Desired behaviour:

SE80 - Create program/class/data element/table/....

==> user exit/badi checks the logon language. When it is not 'EN', the creation will be refused.

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: There is the same question in SAP forum, with some code provided in an answer: https://answers.sap.com/questions/477128/check-original-language-of-repository-objects-when.html

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a exit for this but I haven't remember exact name. You can use general purpose for finding exit. Go to SE24 and open **CL_EXITHANDLER** class, find **GET_INSTANCE** method and add break point. Then start creating item, it will pause on debugger multiple times, try to find suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As @mkysoft suggested, you may implement a check in the **BAdI CTS_REQUEST_CHECK**, method **CHECK_BEFORE_ADD_OBJECTS**, which is invoked when the object is about to be attached to a transport request. Raise the exception CANCEL to make the attachment fail (and so the object is not created too).</strike>

EDIT: sorry, ignore my answer, "this method is NOT released for Customer usage" as said in [note 2150125 - Method CHECK_BEFORE_ADD_OBJECTS not triggered](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002150125)

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: THE METHOD DESCRIBED HERE IS ABSOLUTELY NOT RECOMMENDED.**

As correctly pointed out by the other members there is no standard and customer-exposed method to achieve your requirement, but if you absolutely must enable this check during creation you can use the below method. As well as the [previously offered](https://answers.sap.com/questions/477128/check-original-language-of-repository-objects-when.html) to you, it also involves modification of SAP standard.

There is a system BAdi `CTS_TADIR_SUBSCREEN` that is located inside enhancement point `CTS_ES_TADIR_POPUP`. They are SAP internal and not released for customer usage, so do this at your own risk.

Implementation procedure:

**Step 0**. First thing you need to change is a SAP internal usage flag, for which you need Object Access key which can be obtained from SAP or from SAP partner that made the implementation in your org. In virgin state this BAdi throws the error if you try to implement it

[image]

So hereinafter we assume that you already ticked off this checkbox in BAdi settings

[image]

**Step 1**.

In order to implement the BAdi one need to implement enhancement spot prior to that. This is the most complicated part, because despite we disabled internality flag the SAP-namespaced enhancements must be stored only in SAP-namespaced objects. By SAP namespace I mean non-Z, non-Y and non-T (Test). This means to implement this enhancement, besides modifying the enhancement definition, one need to create, for example, CTS_ES_TADIR named enh.impl., and save it to non-Z package, which you also need to create. Your enhancement implementations selector should look somehow like this

[image]

On the above screen only the second will work, all the rest Z will not.

Every non-Z object need Object Access Key, remember? Too bad. But just to show the proof-of-concept, I will proceed.

**Step 2**. After you created the enh. implementation in SAP-namespace it will propose you to create the BAdi implementation. The same principle applies here: only SAP-namespaced container for SAP-namespaced objects, hence `CTS_TADIR_SUBSCREEN` should have implementing class for example `CL_TADIR_SUBSCREEN`. During the creation of enhancement you will see many warnings

[image]

but finally you should have something like this, where all system-named objects are created and the enhancement/BAdi is activated.

[image]

**Step 3**. In order to get the BAdi working we need to enable this subscreen processing

[image]

during the playing with enhancement I found out that BAdi class is not being triggered standalone, without screen events not enhanced, so to make it work you need to touch a screen enhancement for screen 100

[image]

If you do not wanna modify screen elements logic, just put the dummy enhancement in `SHOW_TADIR` dialog module in the end of the include `LSTRDO18`

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.

MODULE SHOW_TADIR. "<-- create the dummy enhancement here
CALL SUBSCREEN subs_info INCLUDING gv_badi_prog gv_badi_dynnr.
```

for example declaration statement like I did

[image]

**Step 4**. Activate your created BAdi class and put the necessary logic there. I wasn't able to trigger method `GET_DATA_FROM_SCREEN`, but `PUT_DATA_TO_SCREEN` worked fine

[image]

If we put this simple processing for your requirement

```
METHOD cts_if_tadir_subscreen~get_data_from_screen.

  IF object_data-l_mstlang <> 'E'.
    MESSAGE 'Objects in non-English languages are not allowed!' TYPE 'A'.
  ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.
```

it will not allow creating objects in languages other than English.

[image]

The check in method `get_data_from_screen` is being done before showing the screen so language is determined from system logon settings. If to play more with this BAdi, I suppose the method `GET_DATA_FROM_SCREEN` can also be enabled, which will make it possible to check user input, i.e. the case when the user gonna change the default language.